# ¿Como obtener y subir videos a VIMEO?

Tags: php, javascript

**Hola, mundo!**

Mi inconveniente es que trato de trabajar con esta api rest, pero he tenido varios problemas en el intento de integrarla a mi script, aunque ya creo que solucionado esos inconvenientes técnicos, pero ahora al solicitar una lista de videos me lanza el error y al igual que al subir un video a Vimeo desde un URL de Google Drive, este no nunca se sube o carga a Vimeo.

**Declarando la libreria**

```
function __construct($client_id_VIMEO,
        $client_secret_VIMEO,$token_VIMEO,$user_id_VIMEO){

    //cargando la variable con los datos de ZOOM

   $this->fields= array('api_key' => urlencode($api_key_ZOOM),
       'api_secret' => urlencode($api_secret_ZOOM));

   //cargando libreria de VIMEO
   $this-> lib=new Vimeo($client_id_VIMEO, $client_secret_VIMEO);

   $token = $this->lib->clientCredentials($this->scope);
    // use the token
   $this->lib->setToken($token_VIMEO);

   $this->user_id_VIMEO=$user_id_VIMEO;


}
```

Las declaro en el momento de iniciar mi Clase, tuve un incoveniente con este proceso e incluso publique una pregunta sobre ello, pero encontre la [solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891474/vimeo-php-api-make-authenticated-request).

**Obteniendo lista de nombres de los vídeos**

```
function getGrabacionesVIMEO(){
    $videos = $this->lib->request("/users/$this->user_id_VIMEO/videos", ['per_page' => 10,'page' => 1]);
    $nombres=array();
        foreach($videos['body']['data'] as $video) {

            $nombre = $video['name'];
            echo 'mi video' . $nombre;

            }

        }
}
```

Aquí debería poder obtener todos los nombres de los vídeos, pero este no pasa `foreach()` indicando que esta mal estructurado o declarado y desconozco porque si  `$videos['body']['data']` debería ser capas de retornar me un `array` con los vídeos, este fragmento de código lo reclute de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675435/vimeo-api-2016-how-to-display-list-of-users-videos)

**error obtenido**

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /storage/ssd1/102/9066102/public_html/ScriptVZS.php on line 56

**Subiendo un vídeo desde url**
    function

```
uploadGrabacionesV($urlVideo,$nameID){
        $video_response = $this->lib->request("/users/$this->user_id_VIMEO/videos",
            [
                'upload' => [
                    'approach' => 'pull',
                    'link' => $urlVideo
                ],
                'name' => $nameID,
                'privacy' => [
                   'view' => 'nobody'
                 ],

            ],

            'POST'
        );
    }
```

Con este metodo tendria que enviarle la orden al servidor para que este comenzara y subiera un vídeo desde el url de descarga de un video que se [encuentra en Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WJC53ehAATXTjirzz5M8zy8d4D3Y10D9), como lo indica su [ejemplo oficial](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php). Pero este nunca carga nada ni me lanza error al ejecutar el código.

Ya no encuentro que hacer desde el inicio esta api me ha ocasionado problemas, aunque creo que esto me pasa por mi inexperiencia en el tema. **Gracias y espero su pronto apoyo.**

Comment: Abraham depura siempre tus objetos para ver cómo están estructurados y si tienen datos, si te da error en el `foreach`, entonces depura ese objeto haciendo algo como: `var_dump($videos['body']['data']);`  si eso sale `NULL` o vacío, entonces vete directamente a ver lo que hay en el objeto completo: `var_dump($videos);` Ahí sabrás lo que hay y cómo leerlo. Y si no hay nada entonces sabrás que el problema está en otra parte.

Comment: Deberias poner el Request y Reponse de la transaccion.

Answer (score 0):

> A. Cedano

le aplique `var_dump()` al `array` y obtuve su valor y milagrosamente también lo demás (los nombres de los vídeos), con lo respecto a lo de cargar videos, aparentemente aun **VIMEO** no me permite subir videos, porque todavía mi solicitud del permiso de carga esta en proceso de aceptación.